# Replace * with space in .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i want to replace "*" from string in .net

my string is

> *Four Star Pharmacy LLC***failed W/S Audit****

Expected Result

> *Four Star Pharmacy LLC failed W/S Audit*

i have tried this pattern but not working

> [;/'*:?""<>|]

Please help me

Comment: Thanks all of you...
It works now. i have to check this in all scenario for different types of string in which i have to replace other special characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it, no need to use a regex:

```
Dim res = input.Replace("*", " ")
```

Comment: multiple asterisks should be replaced by single space

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex:

```
myString = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\*+", " ");
```

Or without Regex:

```
string r = "Four Star Pharmacy LLC***failed W/S Audit***";
r = r.Replace("*", String.Empty);
```

Probably you can manually add the space afterwards.

For .Net 1.0 String.Empty will not take additional space on the heap but "" requires storage on the heap and its address on the stack resulting in more assembly code. Hence String.Empty is faster than "".

Also String.Empty mean no typo errors.

Comment: multiple asterisks should be replaced by single space

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (this.value.match(/[^*]/g)) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^*]/g, ' ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use next pattern:

```
new Regex(@"\*+").Replace("Four Star Pharmacy LLC***failed W/S Audit***", " ")
```